# Is $5^1$ the maximal power of 5 that divides evenly into ${1000 \choose 500}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to solve an exercise from Hua Loo Keng's Introduction to Number Theory Chapter 1 Section 12 to further my understanding of the material.

Here are the steps I took to arrive at this solution. Did I arrive at the correct answer or did I make a mistake? Thanks in advance for your time and consideration! (also this is my first post on here so apologies if this is poorly worded)

1. The maximal power of a prime number p that divides n! is given by the series $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\rfloor.$$

   - Please note that there are finitely many non-zero terms in the series.
2. ${n\choose r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ and always produces an integer solution.
3. Thus, $${1000 \choose 500} = \frac{1000!}{500!(1000-500)!} = \frac{1000!}{500!500!}.$$
4. If we calculate the maximal power of the prime number 5 that divides evenly into 1000!, we calculate $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac{1000}{5^i}\rfloor = \lfloor\frac{1000}{5^1}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{1000}{5^2}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{1000}{5^3}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{1000}{5^4}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{1000}{5^5}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{1000}{5^6}\rfloor + . . .$$ $$=$$ $$200 + 40 + 8 + 1 + 0 + . . . + 0 + . . . = 249$$
5. The maximal power of 5 that divides evenly into 1000! is 249. We can say that for some positive integer a, the product $a5^{249} = 1000!$ such that a isn't divisible by 5 itself.
6. Similarly, we can calculate the maximal power of the prime number 5 that divides evenly into 500! to be $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac{500}{5^i}\rfloor = \lfloor\frac{500}{5^1}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{500}{5^2}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{500}{5^3}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{500}{5^4}\rfloor + . . .$$ $$=$$ $$100+ 20+ 4 + + 0 + . . . + 0 + . . . = 124$$
7. The maximal power of 5 that divides evenly into 500! is 124. We can then that for some integer b, the product $b5^{124} = 500!$ such that b isn't divisible by 5 itself.
8. Thus, we can state that $${1000 \choose 500} = \frac{1000!}{500!500!} = \frac{a5^{249}}{(b5^{124})(b5^{124})} = \frac{a5^{249}}{b^25^{248}} = \frac{a}{b^2}5.$$
9. Neither a nor b are divisible by 5, which means their quotients or products with other numbers will not result in a integer divisible by 5.
10. Does this mean that the maximal power of 5 that divides evenly into ${1000 \choose 500}$ is 1 (or $5^1$)?

Comment: Yes, your figures 249 and 124  are correct , the conclusion $5^1$   is correct.

Comment: @AadithThiruvallarai Welcome to Math SE. I agree with [Will Jagy's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703940/is-51-the-maximal-power-of-5-that-divides-evenly-into-1000-choose-500#comment9957184_4703940). Also, FYI, using [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem), since in base $5$ we have $1000 = 13000_{5}$ and $500 = 4000_{5}$, then there is one carry when $4000_{5}$ is added to itself to make $13000_{5}$, with this also confirming that $5^1$ is the maximum power of $5$ which is a factor of $\binom{1000}{500}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I didn't know about Kummer's theorem. That is extremely helpful!!! Thank you!